# chartjs. How get line data when hover line?

Tags: javascript, plot, charts, chart.js

I have simple chart.js line chart

[image]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');

var data = {
  labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  datasets: [{
      label: "a1-fam",
      cell_id: 1,
      fill: false,
      data: [2, 2, 5, 7, 10, 12, 18],
    },
    {
      label: "a1-rox",
      cell_id: 1,
      fill: false,
      data: [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    },
    {
      label: "a2-fam",
      cell_id: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: [2, 2, 11, 12, 11, 14, 15],
    },
    {
      label: "a2-rox",
      cell_id: 2,
      fill: false,
      data: [0, 2, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12],
    },

  ]
};

const myChart = new Chart(canvas, {
  type: 'line',
  data: data,
  options: {
    showLines: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

How can I get all line dataset data when I hover line (**line! not dots/squares and etc on line**) using mouse?

Example: I hover line with label `a1-fam` (blue one on img). I what get all it object props and values in console

```
{
      label: "a1-fam",
      fill: false,
      data: [2, 2, 5, 7, 10, 12, 18],
}
```

How can i get it?